# How to properly connect to oracle as sysdba role with GNU SQL?

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle12c

I am using GNU SQL and successfully tested connection with demo user *SCOTT*:

```
:scott ora://scott:tiger@localhost/o12c
```

Now trying to do the same with *SYS*. Referring to the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sql.html) I have to quote the blanks from `as sysdba` with `%20`. But none of these connection strings were successfull:

```
:sys ora://sys%20as%20sysdba:sys@localhost/o12c
:sys ora://sys:sys%20as%20sysdba@localhost/o12c
:sys ora://sys:sys@localhost/o12c%20as%20sysdba
```

There´s no helpful error message. SQL*Plus just prompts me some help with syntax...

Does anyone know how to properly connect to oracle as sysdba role with GNU SQL?

**Update:** I have no reason using GNU SQL instead of sqlplus, it´s just for the testing. In verbose mode you can see the actual connection string. I then came to this

`sql sql:oracle://%20:%20as%20sysdba%27%20#@localhost/o12c` which reults in this connection string:

`/usr/bin/rlwrap sqlplus -L  ' / as sysdba' #@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = o12c) ))' @/tmp/32036.sql.init`

I know it is a hack and you need to be local, oradba ... but if there´s a better way please let me know.

Comment: The simple answer would be to use sqlplus directly. Is there any reason why you would use GNU SQL as a wrapper for sqlplus?

Comment: yeah.. i dont think that works..  i beleive the 'as sysdba' is a connection option.. not part of teh username password..  so unless GNU SQL know about it (and it doesnt apppear to from the linked docs) then you are out of luck.   but i'd be happy to be proven wrong.  maybe  via a varient of `-p <passthrough>``